# how to make button response in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a row of buttons in the bootstrap HTML website when I open it in desktop view it works perfectly, but in mobile view, it is a mess.

here is my code :

```html
<div class="creative ">
    <div class="container" style=" padding-top: 50px">

        <div class="card mt-3" style=" background-color:  rgba(255,255,255,.6);">
            <div class="mt-1 card-body" id="artical">
                {#                <h4>El Gouna</h4>#}
                <a class="btn btn-primary warn" href="#about">
                    <span>Divecenter</span>
                </a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary warn" href="#about">
                    <span>Hotels</span>
                </a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary warn"  href="{% url 'price_list' %}">
                    <span>Price &amp; Booking</span>
                </a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary warn" href="#contact">
                    <span>Book Hotel</span>
............
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [block buttons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/buttons/#block-buttons) on small devices and use [flexbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/#fill) on larger screens like this.

```css
.wrap {
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrap d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex">
  <button class="btn btn-primary flex-md-fill">
    Button
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary flex-md-fill">
    Button
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary flex-md-fill">
    Button
  </button>
</div>
```